# Datepicker - Adicionar eventos ao datesDisabled

Tags: javascript, datepicker

Eu gostaria de adicionar dois eventos como, alert (onclick) e on mouseover, especificamente aos campos das datas desabilitadas, datesDisabled.

A estrutura do meu Datepicker está funcional, vou mostrar aqui o script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#date,#date2').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "pt-BR",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: '+0d',
    datesDisabled: ['25/04/2019', '29/04/2019']
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atribua os eventos `click` e `mouseover` à classe `.disabled-date`, que é a classe das datas listadas na array da opção `datesDisabled:`:

```
$(function(){
   $(document).on("click mouseover", ".disabled-date", function(){
      // faz alguma coisa
   });
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('#date,#date2').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    language: "pt-BR",
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    forceParse: false,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: '+0d',
    datesDisabled: ['25/04/2019', '29/04/2019']
});

$(function(){
   $(document).on("click mouseover", ".disabled-date", function(e){
      console.log(e.type);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<input id="date">
<input id="date2">
```